# What site should a question about coding standards go on?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I have a question regarding coding standards - in particular, the layout of code files, rather than what methods should be used, etc. I am not sure where it should go - maybe Stack Overflow, but it isn't really a programming issue, more of a code issue.

Where should I post this question?

Comment: I just deleted a comment I *just* made, because I guessed this *not* to be an appropriate question for SO, but [Oded](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/140505/oded) posted an answer which makes me question that assumption! +1 still, anyway!

Comment: @AndrewBarber - As usual, it _depends on the question_...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use StackOverflow for this - there is a [coding-style](/questions/tagged/coding-style) tag with nearly 4k uses.

Just be sure that the question is relevant to many people and is not something that can start an argument (if it is it will be closed as not constructive). So, no "is x better then y" questions.

Comment: Most question really about coding standard are not constructive, and as far as I can see the [coding-style] tag is more often misapplied than not.

Comment: And I think my questio has shown that coding style is probably not appropriate in SO. But it should be somewhere - definitively and clearly.

Answer (score 2):

To a large extent coding standards are a matter of opinion---often strongly held opinion. Anything even remotely like brace-style wars is the very heart and soul of "not constructive".

They don't go anywhere.

Comment: You misread that particular question.